# AppCompatXXXX for customized UI cannot be tested

Tags: android, robolectric

A problem for testing customized UI which extends from AppCompatXXXX. Here is the example of the UI from AppCompatTextView. It might be the problem from my side, however, when I change to TextView of this customized UI as parent class it works.

Robolectric 3.8

Here is the small project which cannot go through the tests.
[email-button](https://travis-ci.org/XinyueZ/email-button)

[issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3875)

Comment: Please see [mcve] and include relevant code in the question.

Comment: See the ticket, there is.

Comment: _**in the question**_. Not via links to external sites.

Comment: checkout https://github.com/XinyueZ/email-button // run:  ./gradlew clean test -x :app:lint -x :library:lint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updated gradle to 3.2.0-alpha13, it works.